# Error when trying to delete build definitions in TFS web interface

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm getting a server error when I try to delete build definitions from a project on the Team Foundation Server 2015 web interface.

The error message that pops up is:

```
Error(s):

500: 500: error
TFS.WebApi.Exception: 500: error
    at k (http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=ITI0eYHCCehqqjk6JTyPaR5R793ETLoY2_Lqz191Pyo1:64:375)
    at http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=ITI0eYHCCehqqjk6JTyPaR5R793ETLoY2_Lqz191Pyo1:64:2955
    at d (http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=ITI0eYHCCehqqjk6JTyPaR5R793ETLoY2_Lqz191Pyo1:64:635)
    at http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=ITI0eYHCCehqqjk6JTyPaR5R793ETLoY2_Lqz191Pyo1:64:2888
    at l (http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:8122)
    at http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:8348
    at t.when (http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:3780)
    at t.u.promiseDispatch (http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:2824)
    at http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:1649
    at MessagePort.t (http://timeweb:8080/tfs/_static/tfs/Dev14.M102/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:5773)
```

I also get a similar error when I try to save changes to a build definition.

I'm doing everything with an administrator account on the server.

It's acting like the user has INSERT permission in the database but not DELETE or UPDATE, but I'm not sure if this is the cause and the permissions in the database seem OK (why would they be configured incorrectly after a fresh install?).

I'm using a local SQL Server Express instance. I'm using Windows Authentication for TFS, and I'm able to login with Windows Authentication and manually delete them from the database using SQL Server Management Studio.

I just did another uninstall/fresh install and I'm still seeing this error. Any insight into the cause or solution would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

A SQL Server trace isn't showing any relevant commands being received when I attempt the delete/edit, so it seems like the error is happening before it even reaches out to the database.

Comment: Which web browser you're using? Did you try it with another web browser?

Comment: Tried it on Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS. It's a 500 error, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: What about the log files of the TFS?

Comment: TFS Admin Console has some, but none relating to this error. Event Viewer isn't showing any errors. The IIS logs shows the request and that it returned a 500 error, but no details.

Comment: It seems to be a security problem (using Google I've found a lot of similar problems). Please make sure that the user which is used for login on TFS has all security privileges and is member of all relevant security groups in TFS.

Comment: Which build definition are you deleting? XAML build definition or Vnext build definition?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT One the web interface creates when you click 'add build definition' - it's a custom build definition.

Comment: @codelab I have full permissions on the collection and project. I feel like if it was a permissions issue I'd get a permissions error with a friendly message, not a server error with a stack trace.

Comment: Did you install any extension and use it in your build definition?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT No.

Comment: Does this issue occur with other user?

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure you have enough permission. Such as `edit build definition` . You can use [tf permission command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/permission-command) to list the realted permission info.

For example: `tf permission /user:userID /collection:http://xxx:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`
which will return the modified permission for that user under the collection path. Also work with server path.

Also add your user in **Team Project Administrator Group** and **Build Administrator Group**.

Try to clean browser cache and close the browser then try it again.

Comment: I can't run `tf` - not enough free memory. My account is a Windows admin account. Web interface shows my user is set to Advanced access level. User is both a collection administrator, collection build administrator, project administrator, and build administrator.

Tried it with a fresh browser, no difference.

Repeating what I said above, if it was a permissions issue, should I get a permissions error and not a server error?

Comment: I just ran `TF` from a remote machine and it's saying 'no permissions set' on the project... how is that possible? Why is there a discrepancy between what the web app and `tf` are showing?

Comment: No permissions set just mean you didn't change any default permission. Seems this is the right phenomenon. Could you create a new definition and delete the new crated one? And did this error only occurs with your account? Any other account could delete the definition successfully?

Comment: I haven't tried with other accounts. I can create a new definition, but I still get an error when deleting. I'll have someone else try it with another account.

Comment: Seems the issue only occur with the delete option, if others can delete successfully. Then there must be something wrong with your account.